# Related To query

Tags: relations, relatedto

Struggling to get multiple relationship filtering working. 
So want to filter an entry (people) by one or more of the following:
- location (entries)
- specialism (categories)
- team (categories)

For example, if I have any entries that are related to location X, specialism Y and team Z then show them but when trying to use relatedTo with the `and` parameter I am getting zero results, whether that is in twig or at element API level. I have tried both passing in element ids and objects but with no success, so eg:

```
{% set relatedTo = [
    'and',
    [
        field: team', 
        targetElement:  teamCategories
    ],
    [
        field: location', 
        targetElement:  locationEntries
    ],
] %}
```

Then:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'people' }).relatedTo(relatedTo)  %}
```

But always seems to return zero results when I know there are matching relationships in the CMS.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the has notation in Twig for associative arrays using `{}`, rather than the normal array notation using `[]`.

This should work:

```
{% set relatedTo = [
    'and',
    {
        field: 'team', 
        targetElement:  teamCategories
    },
    {
        field: 'location', 
        targetElement:  locationEntries
    },
] %}
```

---

**Edit**: If you want to conditionally check whether any of the `relatedTo` parameters exist and build the query accordingly, you could do something like this:

```
{% set relatedTo = null %}

{% set locationRelationCriteria = locationEntries ? { field: 'location', targetElement: locationEntries } : {} %}

{% set teamRelationCriteria = teamCategories ? { field: 'team', targetElement: teamCategories } : {} %}

{% set specialismRelationCriteria = specialismCategories ? { field: 'specialism', targetElement: specialismCategories } : {} %}


{% set relationCriteraCount = locationRelationCriteria | length + teamRelationCriteria | length + specialismRelationCriteria | length %}


{# relationCriteriaCount will equal 2 * the number of relation criteria with values, since the length of the criteria hash with values is 2 #}
{# so if relationCriteriaCount > 2, there must be more than one criteria with values, so we'll need to 'and' them together #}

{% if relationCriteraCount > 2 %}

    {% set relatedTo = [ 'and' ] %}

    {# Now go through each criteria and merge if it is not empty #}

    {% if locationRelationCriteria %}
        {% set relatedTo = relatedTo | merge([locationRelationCriteria]) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if teamRelationCriteria %}
        {% set relatedTo = relatedTo | merge([teamRelationCriteria]) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if specialismRelationCriteria %}
        {% set relatedTo = relatedTo | merge([specialismRelationCriteria]) %}
    {% endif %}

{% elseif relationCriteraCount == 2 %}

    {# relationCriteraCount == 2 so there must be only one relation criteria with values #}

    {% set relatedTo = locationRelationCriteria ?: teamRelationCriteria ?: specialismRelationCriteria ?: null %}

{% endif %}

{% if relatedTo %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'people' }).relatedTo(relatedTo) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks Steve - struggling to see how to build this dynamically though, eg build out the elements of the associative array if values are present (if that makes sense)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include conditional checking for related criteria. Is this what you were after?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers and help with this @Steve - so after some struggles have finally got this working.

So needed to pass related ids or elements likes so (using ids for brevity):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'people' }).relatedTo({ 
    targetElement: [
        'and',
        7,
        136
    ] }) %}
```

The issue before was (based on [the documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#passing-multiple-relation-criteria)) abstracting the target elements I wanted to query into separate array elements, eg:

```
[
    'and',
    { targetElement: 7 },
    { targetElement: 136 }
]
```

Hopefully, that helps somebody else experiencing similar issues. The same 
principle works at a plugin/PHP level, eg:

```
$peopleEntries = Entry::find()->section('people')->relatedTo(
    ['targetElement'=>['and',7, 136]]
);
```